# How to use Preference.setLayoutResource() using object

Tags: android, preferences

I am attempting to set a Preference layout in code using setLayoutResource() .  But this method requires an int id.  I have a preset RelativeLayout that I want to pass as an argument, but I get an error saying Preference cannot be applied to RelativeLayout.  I suspect it is because I am not passing an R.layout.id.  I need this to work because I will addPreferences dynamically using instances of the same layout with different attribute setting.  How can I make this work? Thank you.  Sample code below.

```
    rLay=(RelativeLayout)View.inflate(Context,R.layout.account_item, null);
    nameView =(TextView) rLay.findViewById(R.id.account_name);
    numberView =(TextView) rLay.findViewById(R.id.number_name);

    pView = new Preference(Context);
    pView.setLayoutResource(rLay); ///ERROR HAPPENS HERE///
```

Comment: Please post my code, what is Context and where is it declared

Comment: Context is an Activity that this PreferenceFragment is initiated from

Answer (score 0):

If you use same layout with dynamically-changing data,
you can create `AwesomePreference extends Preference`,
then override [onBindView(View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#onBindView(android.view.View)) to changing `TextView`'s text or something like that.

This is working like `ListView`'s `adapter#getView()`.

Also don't forget to call `Preference#notifyChanged()` if you changed bound data.

hope this will help.